# How do I switch the positions of words within a string?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split, ruby-2.4

I have an array of strings, each with at least one space in them.  I would like to tkae the last part of the string and put it at the beginning, for every element in the array.  So for example if I have this in my array

```
["RUBY RAILS"]
```

I would like the result to be

```
["RAILS RUBY"]
```

I tried this

```
data.map! {|str| "#{str.split(/\s+/).last} #{str.split(/\s+/).first}" }
```

but the only problem is that if the string has more than two words the above doesn't work.  If a string has more than two words, like

```
["ONE TWO THREE"]
```

I would want the reuslt to be

```
["THREE ONE TWO"]
```

but my above function doesn't do that.  How can I change my function so that it will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Array#`rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate):

```
["ONE TWO THREE"]
  .map(&:split)               #=> [["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]]
  .map { |ar| ar.rotate(-1) } #=> [["THREE", "ONE", "TWO"]]
  .map { |ar| ar.join(' ') }     #=> ["THREE ONE TWO"]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I notice you didn't have to use a regular expression to split up the string into words.  Does the automatic splitting only occur for regular spaces or will it also occur for other types of spaces (like non-breaking spaces)?

Comment: @Natalia check out [String#`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) for being sure what to use. regex is ok if you know you'll get something more complicated that just a spaced string. You could change in my example to `.map { |string| string.split(/\s+/) }`

Comment: Thanks.  Also I noticed this clause "|ar| join(' ')" should probably be "|ar| ar.join(' ')"